# Отправка капчи на сервис антигейт(java). Ошибка ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE

Tags: java, кодировка, post, base64, captcha

Здраствуйте, хочу отправлять капчу на сервис антигейт, пользуюсь методом post и base64 как сказано в документации - `https://anti-captcha.com/apidoc`
Получаю ошибку `ERROR_ZERO_CAPTCHA_FILESIZE`
В параметр post запроса даю key(мой access token  к акаунту-здесь прим.123456789) и ссылку на капчу
Кодирую в base 64 и отправляю
Не понимаю почему сервис не принимает картинку, вроде кодирует правильно, в интернете в онлайн декодере вставлял код картинки в base64 и получал в ответ свою капчу
Вот мой код :

```
    private static void sendPost(String encodedImage,String key) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://anti-captcha.com/in.php?";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        String urlParameters = "key="+key+"&file="+encodedImage;    
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {  
        String imageString = null;  
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  

        try {  
            ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);  
            byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();  

            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();  
            imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);  

            bos.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return imageString;  
    }  

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    URL url = new URL("http://api.vk.com/captcha.php?sid=579356847070&s=1");
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
    String encodedCaptcha=encodeToString(img, "jpg");
    String key="123456789";
    sendPost(key,encodedCaptcha);


    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Как сказано в [документации](https://anti-captcha.com/apidoc)

Во-первых, вы не передаёте `method`.

Во-вторых, (хотя возможно это и просто ошибка примера к документации), оба метода должны быть в `multipart/form-data`. Вы в лучшем случае отправляете `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, если `setRequestMethod("POST")` его выставляет. 
При том, судя по всему, без `urlencode`. Тогда как base64 штатно может содержать символ `=` в конце - т.е. интерпретирован будет ошибочно. Об этом в документации и сказано:

> IMPORTANT: Do not forget to encode the body with URLEncode, otherwise picture data will arrive scrambled.

Не знаком с Java, поищите, как по-нормальному формируется тело HTTP-запроса.
Ручная конкатенация `"key="+key+"&file="+encodedImage` - это не нормально. Наверняка есть штатный способ, принимающий список параметров со значениями и генерирующий корректную строку тела запроса.
Ну или, хотя бы, как делается `urlencode` вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вы перепутали порядок аргументов? Отправляете:

```
 sendPost(key,encodedCaptcha);
```

Принимает sendPost:

```
void sendPost(String encodedImage,String key)
```

И на место encodedImage имеете key, а там где key - encodedImage

Comment: да нет, здесь просто от руки набросал, в коде все ок